# Python - Uniquely determining which text file an element originated from

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I'm loading in three separate text files using numpy with the code:

```
str = 'data'
Di = np.loadtxt(str+'i.txt', dtype=np.float64) 
Dj = np.loadtxt(str+'j.txt', dtype=np.float64)
Dk = np.loadtxt(str+'k.txt', dtype=np.float64)
```

The text files contain 2-dimensional data with `2` columns and roughly `6000` rows (they all contain `2` columns but the number of rows is variable). Given an element `[a,b]` - how can i uniquely determine which text file it originated from?

I can't entirely ensure that the elements are unique though, the number `[a,b]` may occur in both (for example) the datai and dataj text files - however it is very unlikely, but I can't rule it out entirely.

Edit:

Loading in the text files, for example, gives:

```
Di = [[1   4]      Dj = [[9   4]        Dk = [[2   4]       
      [1   5]            [5   5]              [5   6]
      [4   5]            [3   6]]             [4   7]]

      datai.txt          dataj.txt            datak.txt
```

So given the element `[1  4]` the output would be `datai.txt`, letting me know the element `[1  4]` originated from the `datai.txt` file.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import numpy

Di = numpy.array([[1, 4], [1, 5], [4, 5]])

Dj = numpy.array([[9, 4], [5, 5], [3, 6]])

Dk = numpy.array([[2, 4], [5, 6], [4, 7]])
#>>> 

next(array for array in [Di, Dj, Dk] if ([5, 5] == array).all(1).any())
#>>> array([[9, 4],
#>>>        [5, 5],
#>>>        [3, 6]])
```

?

If you want the index:

```
next(i for i, array in enumerate([Di, Dj, Dk]) if ([5, 5] == array).all(1).any())
#>>> 1
```

or the name:

```
next(k for k, array in {"Di":Di, "Dj":Dj, "Dk":Dk}.items() if ([5, 5] == array).all(1).any())
#>>> 'Dj'
```

---

The

```
([5, 5] == array).all(1).any()
```

is the key part, it does (using [9, 4] for explanation)

```
[9, 4] == array
#>>> array([[ True,  True],
#>>>        [False, False],
#>>>        [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then you `all` along the axis going across.

```
([9, 4] == Dj).all(1)
#>>> array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

And then you check if any of the axis matched.

---

The

```
next(array for array in [Di, Dj, Dk] if CONDITION)
```

makes an iterable that only contains those arrays that satisfy CONDITION, `next` gets the first.

You can use `next(..., fallback)` if you don't like catching `StopIteration`.